# How to use wso2 API Manager and wso2 Identity Server with a single page web application

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I build an angularjs client and a spring boot application. The backend provides some dummy REST-APIs. Now I want to integrate the wso2 Api Manager to manage my REST APIs and the wso2 Identity server to secure it.

So I am using the pre-packaged identity server with API Manager. I am able to authorize the user if he enters the webapp by just redirecting to the WSO2 API Manager Server: 
`window.location.href = https://localhost:9445/oauth2/authorize`

This way I can see the login form of the wso2 Identity Server. After entering my credentials I will be redirected back to my webapp with a new url parameter called `code`.

In the docs I read that I have to make a new request with the newly recieved `code` to get an access token. Here is the problem. I need to send an `Authorization: Basic` header where the value is the base64 encoding of the `client_id:client_secret`. As far as I know it is not sure to keep the client secret key in the javascript code.

In addition I am not really sure if I use the right flow with wso2. Is there a clear tutorial / example out there how I can use wso2 for a web application.

I am using **wso2 Api Manager 1.10.0** and **wso2 Identity Server 5.1.0**.

EDIT: I found out that I need to use the implicit flow for browser / javascipt application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In a browser environment I have to use the "implicit" flow. This way I get an access token from the api management server.